# How can I test the ChangeDataCapture using the IPP API Explorer?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

The feature is documented [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/change_data_capture).

[The Intuit Partner Platform API Explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO), though, doesn't seem to have this as an option.

It sounds like a very handy feature. I'd like to test it, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write some code to call the CDC API.

Run the code.

The API Explorer does not support it.

Comment: Yes, it works just fine. Sample code in PHP in case you're looking for it: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/example_cdc.php

Comment: JournalEntry deletions are not reported, as far as I can tell. I've tested the Purchase deletions DO.

Comment: If you are able to duplicate that, and provide logs, you should post them so we can report it to Intuit as a bug. According to their docs, it *is* supported - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/change_data_capture

Comment: I can reproduce it, and I reported it this morning in a developer support ticket. JE creates and updates appear to work, deletions not.

Comment: Bug confirmed with dev team. Not listed on the [known issues page](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0600_more/qbo_v3_known_issues#/QBO_Data_Services_Known_Issues) yet, but it's QBO-94274.

Comment: This bug appears to be fixed. I tested it today.